# How to differentiate normal potato from the potato that has sweetness?

Tags: potatoes, indian-cuisine

Sometimes, we need to add potato to our dishes like in  *Pulao* and some Indian dry vegetable dishes. But some potatoes have sweetness to them which ruin the flavor of the dish.

Is there a way to differentiate the potatoes which are sweet in flavor from the normal one without tasting?

<sub>Note: I am not talking about Sweet potato, which is a different thing altogether.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there is not a perfect way you can differentiate them except tasting, but you can try following ways which are kinda based on experience as we used to run a grocery store.

### 1. By smelling them

You can smell them while purchasing. If you smell some sweetness, it will have sweetness. Though, it'd require some practice.

### 2. By texture and color

You can differentiate between them by looking at color.

For eg., this one has sweetness.

[image]

While this one doesn't have.

[image]

There is one more, but it works after boiling.

If you boil potato with sweetness, it will get glue-ish.

Comment: What about reddish colour potato ?

Comment: Actually, we don't get these ones here, so can't say.

Comment: Generally, these ones have sweetness and are rich in fibers. https://www.potatogoodness.com/potato-types/

Comment: That potato is not sweet! That's neither a sweet potato nor a yam! It has no sweetness at all. http://www.foodsubs.com/Photos/garnetyam.jpg

Comment: @Chloe We're not talking about sweet potato, but potatoes with some sweetness.

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of potato cultivars which look like the first one in your picture, and dozens if not hundreds which look like the second. Are you sure that it is always the look that matters, or is it possible that your local markets sell one cultivar of each look, and one just happens to be sweeter than the other?

Comment: @rumtscho Well, look doesn't always matter, but I can say that most of the times it's true because I've purchased them many times and we also ran a grocery store.

Comment: @AJ How can you say looks doesn't matter when in your answer you say "You can differentiate between them by looking at color"?

Comment: @Ghostship I hope that you didn't miss the word *always* and the sentence *This one is not always true, but mostly I purchased second ones that didn't have sweetness.*.